# How should I complete the sentence?

Tags: word-choice, particles, word-usage

I have the following sentence:

会社は（　）ですか。...パワー電気です。

I guess you it should be translated as "What is this company? It's the Power Company"?

A classmate suggested:

会社は **どこ** ですか。...パワー電気です

But then it would read "Where is the company? It's the Power Company", right?

How should I complete the sentence?